# Boost Directories to include for visitor design pattern

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, include

I am simply asking what are the necessary include directories to utilize the boost statement:

```
boost::static_visitor<void>
```

I have a Visitor class that utilizes the above boost command as its base class but cannot get my code to compile correctly.  I have a feeling i am missing an include statement but Im not sure which one.

Many thanks!

Comment: The [fine documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/static_visitor.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to use this part of the BOOST variant library you could include the following header

```
#include <boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp>
```

If this does not work you could add the following instead. Although from the compiler errors above, you should only include headers which ''boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp'' requires.

```
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
```

Make sure the location of boost folder is linked when compiled, whatever compiler you are using. In addition, this is a header only file so no libraries need compiling

If none of the above work, you can also try the following

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
```